# Batch script git commit with dynamic comment

Tags: command-line, batch-file, git

I am using a .bat file to commit a project to git and github. I would like it to take one optional argument that is the username of the person calling the file. That will be passed in using the command line. Don't worry about that part, it works fine. The part that is not working is the `git commit -m "%comment%"` line. The `ECHO %comment%` line prints out what I would expect it to print, but then it's not being passed to the git comment. The text `%comment%` is the comment being passed in instead of `Saved on Mon 10/11/2021-21:45:34.59 by makpo`. What am I doing wrong?

```
@ECHO OFF

SET comment=Saved on %date%-%time%

IF "%~1"=="" GOTO COMMIT
SET username=%1
SET comment=%comment% by %username%

:COMMIT
ECHO %comment%
git checkout development
git add .
git commit -m "%comment%"
git push origin
```

**GitHub**
[image]

Comment: You sure about that? `git add .` adds everything that `git` doesn't know about. Isn't `git add -u` or `git commit -a` what you rather want?

Comment: Can you try `call bash -c "git commit -m \"%comment%\""`?